# Variable not holding its value and resetting

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

(Im very new to python and coding in general) Im trying to create a simple python code for a bank login with a predetermined username and password where you can take money out, put money in, view balance and exit. Everything works fine until the code loops in the second while True loop and the "balance" variable resets to 100 but I want it to keep its value until the code ends and I dont know how to do it.

First of all I had the "balance" variable inside the loop but then put it outside because everytime it looped it would just reset but that didnt seem to change anything. But I havent really tried anything else as im quit new to coding.

```
import time
username = "user"
password = "123"
login_count = 0

while True:
    login_count = login_count + 1
    if login_count > 3:
        print("try again later")
        break
    user = input("what is your username?  ")
    pas = input("what is your password?  ")
    if user == username and pas == password:
        print("login in...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("correct!")
        break

balance = 100
while True:
    if login_count > 3:
        break
    option = input("\nwould you like to do: \nwithdraw \ndeposit \nview \nexit \n  ")
    if option == "withdraw":
        withdraw = float(input("how much would you like to withdraw?  "))
        total = (balance - withdraw)
        if total < 0:
            print("you cannot take out that much")
            continue
        print("here is your new balance:  ")
        print(total)
        continue
    elif option == "deposit":
        deposit = float(input("how much would you like to deposit?  "))
        total = (balance + deposit)
        print("here is your new balance: ")
        print(total)
        continue
    elif option == "view":
        print("here is your balance: ")
        print(balance)
        continue
    elif option == "exit":
        print("login out...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("thank you for being a loyal customer!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable `total` two times within the while loop but never change the value of balance. That is why it is always resetted to 100. Here is your code with few changes that makes it work as expected:

```
balance = 100
while True:
    if login_count > 3:
        break
    option = input("\nwould you like to do: \nwithdraw \ndeposit \nview \nexit \n  ")
    if option == "withdraw":
        withdraw = float(input("how much would you like to withdraw?  "))
        
        if (balance - withdraw) < 0:
            print("you cannot take out that much")
            continue
        balance = (balance - withdraw)
        print("here is your new balance:  ")
        print(balance)
        continue
    elif option == "deposit":
        deposit = float(input("how much would you like to deposit?  "))
        balance = (balance + deposit)
        print("here is your new balance: ")
        print(balance)
        continue
    elif option == "view":
        print("here is your balance: ")
        print(balance)
        continue
    elif option == "exit":
        print("login out...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("thank you for being a loyal customer!")
        break
```